# How can I calibrate the touch screen and stylus on HP Pavillion TX 2500?

Tags: 10.10, xorg, resolution, configuration, hp-pavilion

I installed Kubuntu 10.10 on a HP tx2675ee tablet PC (tx2500 series - single touch not multi touch). The touch screen and stylus both work out of the box, however the touch screen is way off calibration wise and the stylus is just a bit out of whack.

How do I calibrate these input methods?

There are posts here and elsewhere referring to editing this path:
`/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-wacom.conf`, but on Kubuntu 10.10 I can't find that file or it's parent directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could go an grab the [xinput calibrator](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xinput_calibrator) which will allow you to get the calibration values for the touchscreen. After that you can set those values using `xinput`.

You can acquire a full list of devices with `xinput list`, a list of all properties of the device with `xinput list-props $device_id`. There should be a property like `Evdev Axis Calibration` which you can set like this:

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Evdev Axis Calibration" 0 4132 0 4135
```