# Help debugging erratic stylus behaviour

Tags: touchscreen, wacom, stylus

I'm on a laptop with Wacom touchscreen, Ubuntu 20.04 and KDE 5.18.8.

The stylus and its eraser (activated by a button) is recognized and works well on most part of the screen, except a little area around the upper-centre. When the stylus is moved there, the pointer suddenly jumps on a completely different part of the screen. You can see this effect in a screenshot below. I zig-zagged the stylus on the screen without detaching it (this behaviour doesn not only happen with Xournal++, used to draw this; it also happens on an empty desktop or on other apps.)

I noticed this problem only today, and never experienced it before, at least until I used the stylus a couple of days ago. Neither the laptop or the pen have received any damage in the meantime.

I tried recalibrating by going to *Settings*>*Input Devices*>*Graphic Tablet*>*Tablet*>*Tablet mapping*>*Calibrate*, but the problem persists, even after reboot.

I'd like to understand if this is a calibration problem, software problem, or hardware – in the latter case I have to contact the manifacturer. Any help in how to assess this?

I checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321706/thinkpad-x1-yoga-3rd-gen-on-ubuntu-20-04-stylus-calibration-erratic) but the only answer is related to Gnome. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285604/external-display-screws-up-stylus-pen-cursor-position/1287399#1287399) is related to external displays, which is not my case. [This question & answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310691/touchscreen-calibration-fails-on-ubuntu-20-04-pixelbook) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1188624/1519798) mention `xinput_calibrator`, but I'm not sure whether I really need that, given that I already tried calibration from the *Settings* menu. Finally [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1324197/1519798) seems to report a different problem, and never received an answer.

The command `xinput list` (as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/8435/1519798)) gives (among other devices)

```
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser        id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

and `xinput list-props 10` gives

```
Device 'Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus':
        Device Enabled (216):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (218): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (343):     0
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (344):       1.000000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (345):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (346):    10.000000
        Device Node (340):      "/dev/input/event9"
        Wacom Tablet Area (353):        0, 0, 34399, 21499
        Wacom Rotation (354):   0
        Wacom Pressurecurve (355):      0, 0, 100, 100
        Wacom Serial IDs (356): 21155, -2145366861, 32875, 0, 0
        Wacom Serial ID binding (357):  0
        Wacom Proximity Threshold (358):        30
        Wacom Pressure Threshold (359): 26
        Wacom Sample and Suppress (360):        2, 4
        Wacom Enable Touch (361):       0
        Wacom Hover Click (362):        1
        Wacom Enable Touch Gesture (363):       0
        Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters (364):   0, 0, 250
        Wacom Tool Type (365):  "STYLUS" (342)
        Wacom Button Actions (366):     "Wacom button action 0" (367), "Wacom button action 1" (368), "Wacom button action 2" (369), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0), "Wacom button action 3" (370)
        Wacom button action 0 (367):    1572865
        Wacom button action 1 (368):    1572867
        Wacom button action 2 (369):    1572866
        Wacom button action 3 (370):    1572872
        Wacom Pressure Recalibration (371):     1
        Wacom Panscroll Threshold (372):        1300
        Device Product ID (341):        1386, 21155
        Wacom Debug Levels (373):       0, 0
```

[image]